# Drupal 7.22 video display in block gone wrong after upgrade

Tags: blocks, wysiwyg, files

I'm  a newbie and I just upgraded to Drupal 7.22 and installed CKEditor as well.
When I edited a block with embedded with CKEditor enabled, the video thumbnail disappeared.
Disabled CKeditor, re-edited the block, thumbnail re-appears.
Re-enabled CKEditor, thumbnail is still there.
Create new block to display same video with same embed code:  No thumbnail.
So, somehow CKEditor is blocking the creation of Full HTML.
Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Have you cleared the caches after enabling or disabling the module?  You should always clear caches upon enabling/disabling modules.

Comment: thanks Patrick, I tried that a few times.  But the block will jsut not recognise full HTML.  I have put in the standard embed code......<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/e9Oa2vslWaU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  but it jsut displays it, doesn't act on it.  i have a feeling i am missing somthing quite basic, but I can't find it!